# No me aparece el resultado del código, variables con texto javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables

tengo un problema con javascript. Estoy practicando variables con texto simplemente para manejar mejor el código. quise hacer una página donde ponga dos números, me haga la suma, y aparezca una etiqueta donde me diga si es "posible" o "imposible" dependiendo de si la suma es mayor o menor a 100. En fin, algo fácil. El tema es que me sale perfecto cuando aplico directamente el document.getElementById('veri1).innerHTMl (el verificador por si la suma es mayor o menor), pero el problema es que cuando quiero hacerlo con variables, no me aparece nada en la página, y mi idea es practicar variables para optimizar el uso. Básicamente esta función se ejecuta cuando doy click en sumar con un evento onclick. La función se ejecuta bien porque la suma me la hace, lo que no aparece es lo segundo
Les dejo el código, gracias:

```
function suma(){
    numero1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    numero2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    total = numero1 + numero2
    document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = total;
    verificando = document.getElementById('veri').innerHTML;
    
    if (total >= 100){
        verificando = 'posible';
    } else {
        verificando = 'imposible';
    }
}
```

Código HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>número 1:</p><input type="number" id="input1"><br>
    <p>número 2:</p><input type="number" id="input2"><br><br>
    <button id="boton" onclick="suma()">Sumar</button>
    <p>suma:</p><p id="suma"></p><br>
    <p>posible:</p><p id="veri"></p>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en tu función, a la hora de asignarle valor a la variable verificando, le estás asignando el valor del innerHTML del id veri a la variable verificando, cuando lo que quieres es asignarle al elemento html el valor de la variable, así que lo que cambié fue la condicional antes de la asignación al elemento, y cambié la posición de verificando y el innerhtml

```
function suma(){
    numero1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    numero2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    total = numero1 + numero2
    document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = total;
    if (total >= 100){
        verificando = 'posible';
    } else {
        verificando = 'imposible';
    }
    document.getElementById('veri').innerHTML = verificando;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me funcionó perfectamente. Lo que si no entiendo, o que cambió la perspectiva, es que al parecer en javascript sí importa de que lado pongas la igualdad, lo cual me parece bastante antilógico porque en matemáticas no interesa si ubicas a la izquierda o a la derecha una igualdad porque se supone que son iguales. Evidentemente tengo mucho que aprender sobre la lógica del lenguaje de javascript. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Generalmente en programación, la lógica que se sigue es:
A = B
Lo que indica, que a A le asignas el valor de B, y no viceversa